# Analysis of longitudinal data with a change in DV - SEM, MANOVA or not possible?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, structural-equation-modeling, autoregressive, manova

I have a dataset in which a (latent) construct (e.g., math performance) is measured at different time points using different psychological tests.
The first data point is comparable to an assessment center. In my setup, there are four groups of participants, each one taking a different assessment center.

The following measurements represent performance at various stages in a study program (therefore measured using standardized tests appropriate for the stage in the program). This means that the dependent variable changes based on the time in the program (i.e., the test after year 1 is different from the test after year 2).
This question is very similar to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148317/longitudinal-data-analysis-where-meaning-and-metric-of-response-variable-varies), which unfortunately died out over time.

I am now interested in the intraindividual performance of the participants over time and also correlate that to their performance in the assessment center and which type of assessment center they did.
I think a "regular" mixed model for repeated measures would not be appropriate due to the differences in mean (and SD structure) for the different tests.
For the basic question of correlation between assessment center performance and ONE measurement, a mixed model could work, but I would be missing out on the intraindividual "history" of the participants over multiple measurements.

I considered using an SEM (e.g., a Latent-State-Trait model) in which the latent construct (math performance) is treated as a higher-order latent factor.
I was also considering a MANOVA approach to use the type of assessment center as the IV.

Is it generally possible to answer the question above?
Are the SEM and/or MANOVA the right tools for this kind of question? Are there better ones?

Comment: Given that the tests are different at each time, what would it tell you if you found that the means were different (or did not find that they were different)?

Comment: To be honest, I would not even be that interested in the actual mean values at each data point (as they are probably all different, just like you describe). To me, it would be important to know if the intraindividual trends for the different assessment center types differ from each other (e.g. group A was better at point 2 but group B has caught up at point 3).

Comment: I see. I would use SEM then, because it's easier to handle heterogeneity of variance.